# Issue with string replacement on a lengthy string

Tags: string, c#-3.0

I am facing an issue when trying to replace the newline character /n from a json string .

Here iam serializing my response data using JsonConvert and then trying to find and replace /n but its not finding any newline characters even if it has multiple.

The serialized text is having around 3k lines

```
var jsonResponse = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response);

string formatted = string.Empty;
// Not working

            if (jsonResponse.Contains(Environment.NewLine))
            {
                formatted = jsonResponse.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "");
            }
```

But if i save this above jsonResponse to a .txt file and then read all text to a variable its working fine.Its finding the new line character and then replaces it.

```
var text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"D:\TestData.txt");

// Working

            if (text.Contains(Environment.NewLine))
            {
                formatted = text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "");
            }
```

How can i make this work with out loading from a text file.Please suggest

Comment: You should debug your application and see what `Environment.NewLine` returns. If I'm not wrong, it's `\r\n` on windows, which won't match with your `/n`.

Comment: I tried that even if i give /n the result is same its not finding any match.

Comment: new line character is either \r or \n why are you using /n?
You will need to load the file in memory anyway to replace the new line character. You should better off replacing it directly. no need to put an extra check "if (text.Contains(Environment.NewLine))" it will traverse the whole text anyway.